# Using ViewshedGenerate in Java (can't instantiate SWIGTYPE_p_p_char)

Tags: gdal, java

Using GDAL Java of this package:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm trying to extract a viewshed from a HGT SRTM file:

```
        Vector<String> options = new Vector<>();
        options.add("-json");
        InfoOptions infoOptions = new InfoOptions( options ); 
        
        String gdalSource = "S22W050.hgt";
        gdal.AllRegister();     
        Dataset hDataset = gdal.Open(gdalSource, gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);
        System.out.println( gdal.GDALInfo(hDataset, infoOptions ) );
        
        Band band = hDataset.GetRasterBand(1);
```

I'm fine until here but `Dataset gdd = gdal.ViewshedGenerate( )` is asking me to use `SWIGTYPE_p_p_char` in fourth parameter and I have no way to find any concrete example to show how to use this type. By googling this I just found interfaces and method signatures but none showing how to actually use it.

This is how I'm trying to work until now, but although I have no error and the TIFF file was created, it is corrupted or empty (I can't open it using my Windows).

`Dataset gdd = gdal.ViewshedGenerate(band, "GTiff", "testviewshed.tif",null,-49.5, -21.5, 2, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0.8514, ViewshedMode.GVM_Max, 10000 );`

This is somehow strange because if I do a `gdal.GDALInfo(gdd, infoOptions );` this is the output:

```
{
  "description":"/testviewshed.tif",
  "driverShortName":"GTiff",
  "driverLongName":"GeoTIFF",
  "files":[
    "/testviewshed.tif"
  ],
  "size":[
    3601,
    3601
  ],
  "coordinateSystem":{
    "wkt":"GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]",
    "dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping":[
      2,
      1
    ]
  },
  "geoTransform":[
    -50.0001388888888911,
    0.0002777777777778,
    0.0,
    -20.9998611111111124,
    0.0,
    -0.0002777777777778
  ],
  "metadata":{
    "IMAGE_STRUCTURE":{
      "INTERLEAVE":"BAND"
    }
  },
  "cornerCoordinates":{
    "upperLeft":[
      -50.0001389,
      -20.9998611
    ],
    "lowerLeft":[
      -50.0001389,
      -22.0001389
    ],
    "lowerRight":[
      -48.9998611,
      -22.0001389
    ],
    "upperRight":[
      -48.9998611,
      -20.9998611
    ],
    "center":[
      -49.5,
      -21.5
    ]
  },
  "wgs84Extent":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
      [
        [
          -50.0001389,
          -20.9998611
        ],
        [
          -50.0001389,
          -22.0001389
        ],
        [
          -48.9998611,
          -22.0001389
        ],
        [
          -48.9998611,
          -20.9998611
        ],
        [
          -50.0001389,
          -20.9998611
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "bands":[
    {
      "band":1,
      "block":[
        3601,
        2
      ],
      "type":"Byte",
      "colorInterpretation":"Gray",
      "noDataValue":0.0,
      "metadata":{
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So IFAIK it should be ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Vince. My english is not very sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found a better way, WITHOUT USING GDAL JAVA!

```
    String lat = "-21.5";
    String lon = "-49.5";
    String dist = "10000";
    String observerHeight = "0";
    String targetHeight = "0";

    String[] environments = null;
    File workdir = new File( workdirFolder );
    String[] command = { 
        "./viewshed.sh",
        lon,
        lat,
        dist,
        inputFileName, 
        outputFileName,
        observerHeight,
        targetHeight
    };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, environments, workdir); 
    process.waitFor();
```

and viewshed.sh

`gdal_viewshed -co TILED=YES -co compress=lzw -md $3 -ox $1 -oy $2 -oz $6 -tz $7 -a_nodata 0 $4 $5`

All is working now. More flexible to changes.

Comment: Hi Julien. Thanks for editing, but you changed what I mean. I mean "I've found a better way: ```YOU DO NOT USE JAVA TO DO THIS``` and not ```Uh ok, I'll not use Java myself.``` My intention is to tell people not spend time using ```org.gdal```. Wrap a bash script instead. It is more flexible.